# Sending an email using python with hashtag #

Tags: python, email, hyperlink, hashtag

I am new to python and trying to send an email. That works fine and perfectly. 
But my problem is, that i'd like to send a link with a hashtag, e.g:

```
link = "https://www.google.com/#q=let+me+google+that+for+you"
Bodymessage = "That is your link: %s" %(link)
```

As you can see, there is a hashtag in my link. And python 'thinks' that I want to set a comment. What can I do?

Comment: What do you mean by "python thinks". What does "python do" to let you say that ? e.g. your IDLE colors it in such a manner that it appears as beeing considered as a comment ?

Comment: "Hashtag" is not a general term for any string (in any context) beginning with `#`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\` before the hashtag. `\` is the escape character.

What it's doing in this particular case is that it is escaping the # so that it's treated as a character of the string rather than commenting out the rest of the line, similar to:

```
link = "https://www.google.com/\#q=let+me+google+that+for+you"
```

Answer (score 0):

python does not consider `#` as a comment if you put it inside quotes.

```
string = "foobar#something"
print string

>>> 
foobar#something
>>>
```

So it's the module you use for requesting the url that seems to cause the issue. urllib2 does not behave like that:

```
import urllib2

url = "https://www.google.com/#q=let+me+google+that+for+you"
res = urllib2.urlopen(url)
print res.read()
```